# Cassandra stress test gives UnavailableException

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-stress

I just set up a brand new instance of DSE 3.2, 3 nodes on Ubuntu via tarball.
Everything seems to be set up fine:

```
    bin/nodetool status
Datacenter: Cassandra
=====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.5.77  102.23 KB  256     34.6%             cb04a5a3-8135-42f0-b723-761284355965  rack1
DN  192.168.5.71  41.11 KB   256     31.4%             d2c049fd-24ac-49d5-ada2-ca6991e0b70b  rack1
UN  192.168.5.74  74.84 KB   256     34.0%             4b188d14-f3e0-4d34-a148-816350d6b69e  rack1
```

i can also run the cli and cqlsh .
However when i run the stress test, it gives:

```
:/data/dse-3.2.0/resources/cassandra/tools# bin/cassandra-stress
INFO  - 2013-11-19 17:24:57.241; com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfig; Loading settings from file:/data/dse-3.2.0/resources/dse/conf/dse.yaml
INFO  - 2013-11-19 17:24:57.390; org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor; Loading settings from file:/data/dse-3.2.0/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  - 2013-11-19 17:24:57.504; org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor; Data files directories: [/var/lib/cassandra/data]
INFO  - 2013-11-19 17:24:57.504; org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor; Commit log directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
INFO  - 2013-11-19 17:24:57.505; org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor; DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  - 2013-11-19 17:24:57.505; org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor; disk_failure_policy is stop
INFO  - 2013-11-19 17:24:57.505; org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor; Legacy authentication config found. Existing authentication data will be migrated to a system keyspace.
INFO  - 2013-11-19 17:24:57.525; org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor; Global memtable threshold is enabled at 890MB
INFO  - 2013-11-19 17:24:57.541; com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch; Setting my role to Cassandra
INFO  - 2013-11-19 17:24:57.691; org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor; Not using multi-threaded compaction
INFO  - 2013-11-19 17:24:58.043; com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfig; Load of settings is done.
Created keyspaces. Sleeping 1s for propagation.
total,interval_op_rate,interval_key_rate,latency/95th/99th,elapsed_time
Operation [1] retried 10 times - error inserting key 0000001 ((UnavailableException))

Operation [2] retried 10 times - error inserting key 0000002 ((UnavailableException))

Operation [3] retried 10 times - error inserting key 0000003 ((UnavailableException))

..

84,8,8,5.5,14.6,39.8,1
FAILURE
```

Why is that ? 
cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 3):

```
DN  192.168.5.71  41.11 KB   256     31.4%             d2c049fd-24ac-49d5-ada2-ca6991e0b70b  rack1
```

Means that node is down, since that node is responsible for 1/3rd of the data stress will fail whenever attempting to insert to that partition.

Comment: You re right, didnt see this; strange though, as i also had tried with RF=1 so at that time it should have worked. Working now, thanks!

Comment: RF=1 means there is only one copy for any given partition key. RF=2 would have worked (given consistency one)